# How to retrieve group by date data in Asp.Net?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, datetime, group-by

I'm trying to retrieve group by date from database using entity framework query like below :

```
var AllDates = db.Crops_Cert.Where(n => n.DateInYear != null).Select(g => new { DateInYear = g.DateInYear }).GroupBy(w => w.DateInYear).ToList();
```

I got this result when present it in view :

[image]

The model :

```
public partial class Crops_Cert
    {
        [Key]
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Crops_Type { get; set; }
        public Nullable<int> Region { get; set; }
        public Nullable<System.DateTime> DateInYear { get; set; }
 
}
```

I do not know the cause of this issue and how resolve it, could anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure because I cannot reproduce it, but should be a problem with the Nullable type of DateTime.

Try this one:

```
var AllDates = db.Crops_Cert.Where(n => n.DateInYear != null).Select(g => new { DateInYear = g.DateInYear ?? DateTime.MinValue }).GroupBy(w => w.DateInYear).ToList();
```

Comment: Thanks Nicola for your response, I got this error when I add your code : 'System.NotSupportedException: 'LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.DateTime GetValueOrDefault()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Comment: Ok, try with coalescing for null type. Look at the answer.

Comment: I got same issue in the image I mentioned previously